# Can different Views for different User Categories be created in SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint, forms, view

I need to limit different Users to view only the information assigned to them in their View. For exapmle (Sales will only see what is in Sales's View).

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not entirely sure I understand your question, but you can try enabling audience targeting (List Settings -> Audience Targeting Settings ) and then create a Sales view with a filter, setting the Target Audience = Sales (assuming you have a Sales group).

There are a number of products that claim to implement column level permissions: [Google](http://www.google.com/search?q=sharepoint+column+permissions)

Comment: I need to create different groups of users, and separate Views for these groups that will limit the information they can see, whithout giving them access to the main list.

Comment: There are a number of products that claim to implement column level permissions: [Google](http://www.google.com/search?q=sharepoint+column+permissions)

Answer (score 1):

We use SharePoint [Forms Designer](http://spform.com) tool that allows to create multiple forms for the same content type and show specific based on the current user membership, permissions or even current item field values.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but it depends on the actual information you need to save. For instance, if every document/item has one and only one department attached to them, you can create multiple folders in the root of your document library/list and assign read permissions on those folders. Then, create a recursive view to combine all folders together.

You can use audience targeting as well, just be aware that it hides information from users only visually - they can still access it, if they know the URL.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Infowise Smart List Lite which is a free solution for **view permissions**, column permissions, tab permissions and more. it's basically a tool that helps using SharePoint lists as a real forms.
Infowise Smart List lite is the light version of Smart List Pro. the only difference between them is that Smart List lite is limited for 3 sets of rules (and it's also free :)).

check it out at - http://www.infowisesolutions.com/product.aspx?id=SmartListLite

Comment: Are you sure this answers his question? Your summary only lists permissions, not "Views" as he asks for.